# How to make multiple postman requests with cycle-generated variables?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Task: I've got some id's on a server and I need to remove some of them while it's only possible to delete one per request.

Result example: requests https://ids.com/***1*** and https://ids.com/***2***

Actual result: just one request https://ids.com/2

Request:

```
https://ids.com/{{id}}
```

Environment (empty var):

```
id:
```

Pre-request Code:

```
const ids = [1, 2]

while (ids.length) {
  pm.environment.set("id", ids.shift());
}
```

Test:

```
const id = pm.environment.get("id");

if (id)
    postman.setNextRequest("request_name");
else
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
```

Comment: what is the problem with the above code ? does it making any change?

Comment: once try with the delay of 5 secs for each request in collection runner.